# Automatically switch to detail report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In SSRS 2008, is it possible load detail report from summary report automatically? The idea is that the user watch summary report for 30 seconds and then details report loads and switch back and forth.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done at the report level. However, you can do it at the page level if you are implementing a web application with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Just go to the properties of the text box, select `Navigation Tab` and go to `Jump to url`, then write your javascript with interval.